# IE Error : Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined

Tags: internet-explorer, innerhtml

This simple piece of code (progress bar) works fine everywhere except IE (tried 9 and 8) :

```
      <!-- Progress bar holder -->
      <div id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #eee;"></div>
      <!-- Progress information -->
      <div id="information" style="width"></div>

      <?php

      // Total processes
      $total = 10;

      // Loop through process
      for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){
      // Calculate the percentation
      $percent = intval($i/$total * 100)."%";

     // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
     echo '<script language="javascript">
     document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';   background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.";
</script>';

// This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

// Send output to browser immediately
flush();

// Sleep one second so we can see the delay
sleep(1);
}

// Tell user that the process is completed
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process completed"</script>';

 ?>
```

IE shows the error " Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined ".
The problem seems to be here :

```
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
```

div in this case doesn't work properly in IE (at least as far as I understood)

Tried to fix it by myself, but it's too complicated for me. Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks )

Comment: It works fine for me on IE 8... have you tried disabling any addons, accelerators, etc? and What are your security settings?

Comment: Hm...Tried on three absolutely different comps (IE 9,8,6)...no luck. Do you see the progress bar or just container ??

Comment: Saw both the bar and the container.  Have you tried disabling addons, accelerators, etc, and lowering security settings?

Comment: I'm not using IE on a regular basis, just for the tests. No addons or anything, basic version. Tried to make the security to the lowest level possible, still nothing. Strange ...

Comment: Hmm... Sorry; can't help you there :(

Comment: Same situation, seeing a similar error for the Facebook code as well.

Answer (score 1):

the document is probably not loaded yet.

try

```
window.onload = function() {
    // your code
}
```

or I always use jQuery

```
$(function () {
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is most likely to ensure your document has the correct structure.

This does not work :

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML="HELLO WORLD";
</script>
```

This does work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML="HELLO WORLD";
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```